# Display the BLOB objects in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

I have a query which retrieves the data from Oracle DB. The table which I am retrieving contains one BLOB type column. When I tried to output it as

```
<cfoutput>#query.blobColumn#</cfoutput>
```

Its giving me the error "ByteArray objects cannot be converted to strings". I tried using

```
<cfoutput>#ToString(query.blobColumn)#</cfoutput>
```

Then it worked, but I am getting the content as "��t�".

Is there any way we can display some text of the blob(XML file) and if user clicks on it, we can display/download the full content of it?

This is the Code i am using

```
<cfloop query="UpdateResult">  
  <tr id="dataRow">  
     <cfloop index="ColName" `list="#UpdateResult.ColumnList#">  
       <cfif isBinary(UpdateResult[ColName[UpdateResult.CurrentRow])>                  
         <td>#CharsetEncode(UpdateResult[ColName][UpdateResult.CurrentRow], "ISO- 8859-1" ) #</td> 
        <cfelse>
          <td>#UpdateResult[ColName][UpdateResult.CurrentRow]#</td> 
       </cfif> 
      </cfloop>  
    </tr>
 </cfloop>`
```

Comment: Do the � characters appear on the page?

Comment: Yes, I am displaying it in Table format And I got this output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try using the [CharsetEncode()](http://cfquickdocs.com/cf8/#CharsetEncode) function.

```
<cfoutput>#CharsetEncode( query.blobCoulmn, "us-ascii" )#</cfoutput>
```

From the documentation:

> Adobe recommends that you use this
>   function, and not the ToString
>   function, to convert binary data to
>   strings in all new applications.

It supports many character sets, us-ascii is only used as an example.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Well, I am using a common code to display all the blob Types and String Types using the cfloop. 
When I got the Column which is of not BLOB Type Then Got "Parameter 1 of the CharsetEncode function, which is now '', must be a valid binary object"
So Is there anyway we can Identify which type it is and if it BLOB type only then we will use CharsetEncode()?

Comment: I take it you cannot refer to them as "query.blobColumn", "query.stringColumn", etc?  Without seeing the code, the best I can offer is the 'isBinary()' function.  It may do what you're asking.

Comment: HI,
I am still getting the Same Problem. Below is my code. Can you please suggest
 
<cfloop query="UpdateResult">
      <tr id="dataRow">
     <cfloop index="ColName" list="#UpdateResult.ColumnList#">
         <cfif isBinary(UpdateResult[ColName[UpdateResult.CurrentRow])>
  <td>#CharsetEncode(UpdateResult[ColName][UpdateResult.CurrentRow], "ISO-   8859-1" ) #</td>
 <cfelse>
  <td>#UpdateResult[ColName][UpdateResult.CurrentRow]#</td>
 </cfif>
 </cfloop>
 </tr>
</cfloop>

I Tried all Encodings.. still its saem Problem :(

Comment: I'm not sure what else to suggest.  Ben Doom's suggestion of using a CLOB column instead of BLOB is a good one, perhaps you can try that.  XML is text and thus should be stored in a Character Large OBject (CLOB) rather than a BLOB.

Comment: But Unfortunatly, I am getting these Resultset from other Application DB. So I cannot change the DataTypes :(

Comment: There isn't much more I can think of to try.  The `BinaryEncode()` converts a binary object into a string of hex values.  Perhaps you could do something with that string.  There must be a better solution!  Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Answer (score 3):

If the BLOB is binary data, then displaying it as a string won't work.  Look into using [CFCONTENT](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/Tags_c_11.html#2850760) to deliver data in binary format.  For the end user to receive it properly, you'll probably need to specify an appropriate MIME type.

Comment: Hi Ben, My BLOB is a XML data

Comment: While you can use a BLOB for XML (hey!  everthing is binary!) most people would use an XMLtext, text, ntext, CLOB, or similar field.  BLOB stands for Binary Long OBject.

Comment: I certainly would use CLOB for XML data.